# Deploy unity metro app on Local Computer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps

I have run into a problem. I have created a test unity project and did this:

Have created a build:

[image]

Opened solution in VS

[image]

And tried to launch on my laptop for test:

[image]

I have tried to change build setting to x64 - it doesn't find some files. But when i change to x86 it shows SplashScreen, but fails somwhere here:

[image]

**Where is the problem, and how to fix this?**

Comment: After looking at your Error in Screenshot if you change your Architecture to ARM I hope it will try to Build your project..

Build - Configuration Manager - Change your target platform to ARM;

Let me know whether it will helpful or not :)

Comment: offcourse not. as it is seen on 3 screenshot it says: Registration of app failed... because you build ARM but your computer is x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if its being solved but i like to answer this question since i encountered the same problem and i solved it myself.

You just need to change build setting from Debug to Master. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to have checked some pre-resquisites :

- You need to have a [Developper certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx) <- Very Important to get your app on METRO
- And you need to associate it with your app version of Visual studio
- Then you can load your Unity sln inside Visual Studio
- Then you compile
- But you still need to get the app installed

Did you have all this ready?

Comment: I have a certificate, but not desctop VS - first time hear of this! I develop metro apps for over a year, and test them on my machine and tablets - and all is fine.

Comment: Yes i understand my mistake now, i had the VS express version and the standalone and the apps version were separate maybe it changed now, corrected

Comment: 1) Have certificate. But other points i don't know how to do, could you provide a link>